# How do I set key password from environmental variable?

Tags: ant

I want to avoid being prompted for the password during a build, but I also want to keep it out of the files so I was trying to set it up so I can type this into command prompt:

```
SET password=pword
ant release
```

My `ant.properties` file looks like this:

```
key.store=../KeyStore/Project.keystore
key.alias=project
key.store.password=${env.password}
key.alias.password=${env.password}
```

In my `build.xml` I have the line:

```
<property environment="env" />
```

As far as I understand from [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) that's all I need, but it doesn't work, says the password is wrong (note I have tripple check it's right, and hard coded it in the `ant.properties` to test).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was simply the order of the lines in the `build.xml`.

The line with the `env` must be above the `ant.properties` line.

```
<property environment="env" />               
<property file="ant.properties" />
```